# DBD-Oracle 1.74 install with Oracle Client 12.1.0.2

Tags: oracle, perl, gcc, aix

System environment is:
 OS: AIX 7.1 TL3 SP5
 Perl: 5.22.0 with DBI 1.633
 gcc: 4.8.3
 Oracle: Client 12.1.0.2.3 (Administrator install)

Running make stops on this error:
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-bI:/usr/lib/iocp.exp'

Originally, client 12.1.0.1.7 was installed, I was able to install DBD-Oracle with that version, but not with the new update.

When installing the new client, I had to enable iocp (I/O Completion Ports) in AIX in order to install it.  That seems to be what gcc is complaining about.

Has anyone had any luck with this version of Oracle client/DBD-Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Well, **-bI:/usr/lib/iocp.exp** is an option for the linker, not for gcc; edit the script/Makefile in question, change it to **-Wl,-bI:/usr/lib/iocp.exp**

Answer (score 0):

That did it, there were 2 places in the Makefile that needed the change. There were other places in the file that I saw the -Wl,-bI but for some reason not on the iocp lines.

Thank you for your help.